# Apache POI : easy way to compare worksheets?

Tags: apache, compare, apache-poi

I need to compare two worksheets with Apache POI.  Is there an easy way to do this, for instance a worksheet compare function, or must I compare each cell?

Comment: How do you define "compare"? What are you business rules on what is the same / different? Styles? Cells? Contents? Colours? etc

Comment: if the values in the cells are different, then the cells are different and then the worksheets are different

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try iterating through all the cells and calculating a running hash or something like that. You run it twice, once for each worksheet and if the hash is the same - the worksheets are the same. AFAIK, there is no out-of-the-box method doing that.

I believe this is a better approach than doing a compare on a cell-to-cell basis since you'll be having only one worksheet opened at once (as opposed to two worksheets in the cell-by-cell approach).

Answer (score 5):

As this is one of the first issues that comes up on Google about comparing POI workbooks, I'd like to share a solution that works for unit testing. I found a good Hamcrest matcher to solve the issue:

http://baddotrobot.com/blog/2012/09/14/diff-excel-with-java-and-hamcrest/

Basically, import the library in through Maven (detailed in the Github README). Once you have two POI workbooks, you write an assertion similar to this:

```
MatcherAssert.assertThat("Workbooks to be identical", actualWorkbook,
    WorkbookMatcher.sameWorkbook(expectedWorkbook));
```

> Note: I use MatcherAssert here to get retrieve more detailed notes on comparison, but JUnit Assert is usable as well. This is noted on the author's website.

It's available on [GitHub](https://github.com/tobyweston/simple-excel) and through the author's [personal Maven repository](http://www.robotooling.com/maven/).

Answer (score 1):

```
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.junit.Assert;


public class CompareExcel {

    public static void assertWorkbooksEqual(final XSSFWorkbook workbookA, final XSSFWorkbook workbookB) {
        for (int i = 0; i < workbookA.getNumberOfSheets(); i++) {
            final XSSFSheet sheetA = workbookA.getSheetAt(i);
            final XSSFSheet sheetB = workbookB.getSheetAt(i);

            compareTwoSheets(sheetA, sheetB);
        }
    }

    private static void compareTwoSheets(final XSSFSheet sheetA, final XSSFSheet sheetB) {
        final int firstRowA = sheetA.getFirstRowNum();
        final int lastRowB = sheetA.getLastRowNum();


        final String sheetName = sheetA.getSheetName();
        Assert.assertEquals(sheetName, sheetB.getSheetName());

        Assert.assertEquals("In sheet: " + sheetName, firstRowA, sheetB.getFirstRowNum());
        Assert.assertEquals("In sheet: " + sheetName, lastRowB, sheetB.getLastRowNum());

        for(int i=firstRowA; i <= lastRowB; i++) {

            final XSSFRow rowA = sheetA.getRow(i);
            final XSSFRow rowB = sheetB.getRow(i);

            compareTwoRows(sheetName, rowA, rowB);
        }
    }

    private static void compareTwoRows(final String sheetName, final XSSFRow rowA, final XSSFRow rowB) {
        if((rowA == null) && (rowB == null)) {
            return;
        }
        Assert.assertNotNull("In sheet: " + sheetName, rowA);
        Assert.assertNotNull("In sheet: " + sheetName, rowB);

        final int firstCellA = rowA.getFirstCellNum();
        final int lastCellA = rowA.getLastCellNum();

        Assert.assertEquals("In sheet: " + sheetName, firstCellA, rowB.getFirstCellNum());
        Assert.assertEquals("In sheet: " + sheetName, lastCellA, rowB.getLastCellNum());

        for(int i=firstCellA; i <= lastCellA; i++) {
            final XSSFCell cellA = rowA.getCell(i);
            final XSSFCell cellB = rowB.getCell(i);
            compareTwoCells(sheetName, cellA, cellB);
        }
    }

    private static void compareTwoCells(final String sheetName, final XSSFCell cellA, final XSSFCell cellB) {
        if((cellA == null) && (cellB == null)) {
            return;
        }
        Assert.assertNotNull(cellA);
        Assert.assertNotNull(cellB);

        String valueA = null;
        String valueB = null;

        Assert.assertEquals(cellA.getCellTypeEnum(), cellB.getCellTypeEnum());

        switch(cellA.getCellTypeEnum()) {
            case NUMERIC:
                valueA = String.valueOf(cellA.getNumericCellValue());
                valueB = String.valueOf(cellB.getNumericCellValue());
                break;
            case STRING:
                valueA = cellA.getStringCellValue();
                valueB = cellB.getStringCellValue();
                break;
            default:
                Assert.fail(
                        String.format(
                                "Unexpected cell type '%s' in sheet: '%s' row: '%s' column: '%s'",
                                cellA.getCellTypeEnum().name(),
                                sheetName,
                                cellA.getRowIndex(),
                                cellA.getColumnIndex()
                        ));
        }

        Assert.assertEquals(
                String.format(
                        "Cell values do not match in sheet: '%s' row: '%s' column: '%s'",
                        sheetName,
                        cellA.getRowIndex(),
                        cellA.getColumnIndex()
                ),
                valueA, valueB);
    }
}
```